# What is a Peachy Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Peachy Word™**.

Use the list of examples below to find out what this rule is.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Peachy Words™}&\textbf{Not Peachy Words™}\\
\hline
\text{GROAN}&\text{GRUNT}\\
\hline
\text{BYE}&\text{FAREWELL}\\
\hline
\text{TONES}&\text{RINGING}\\
\hline
\text{MONKEYS}&\text{APES}\\
\hline
\text{SEVEN}&\text{EIGHT}\\
\hline
\text{ASH}&\text{SMOKE}\\
\hline
\text{ROWAN}&\text{WILLOW}\\
\hline
\text{HALLO*}&\text{GREETINGS}\\
\hline
\text{MOTOR*}&\text{CYCLE}\\
\hline
\text{NOTHING}&\text{NOUGHT}\\
\hline
\text{CASTS}&\text{THROWS}\\
\hline
\text{FARTING}&\text{BURPING}\\
\hline
\text{HOUSE*}&\text{HOME}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

($^*$ denotes an Extra Peachy Word™.)

Text-only version for analysis:

```
GROAN      GRUNT
BYE        FAREWELL
TONES      RINGING
MONKEYS    APES
SEVEN      EIGHT
ASH        SMOKE
ROWAN      WILLOW
HALLO*     GREETINGS
MOTOR*     CYCLE
NOTHING    NOUGHT
CASTS      THROWS
FARTING    BURPING
HOUSE*     HOME
```

Comment: Have we officially ditched the Excel format?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 You mean the table in image format with the yellow? I never used that: too much trouble, when a table in maths formatting is much easier. So no, not officially, just personal taste :-)

Comment: I thought @greenturtle3141 was referring to the CSV-formatted plaintext that has appeared at the bottom of many of these puzzles.

Comment: I saw this one pretty quickly but it just leapt out at me (firstly I just saw the Peachyness of tones), but after I also couldn't work out why `FARTING` was not extra Peachy. FYI there is also one possibly Peachy Word™ in the Not Peachy Word™ list (`CYCLE`), although it is uses a spelling variant of a fairly localised [word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sile).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe a Peachy Word™ is one where

> you can remove the letter right at the middle (or remove the peach pit) and still end up with a meaningful word. *This attempt is further validated by the fact that all the Peachy Words™ have an odd number of letters.*

Here is the list of Peachy Words™ explained:

> `GROAN    -> GRAN
>
> BYE      -> BE
>
> TONES    -> TOES
>
> MONKEYS  -> MONEYS (acceptable according to Collins)
>
> SEVEN    -> SEEN
>
> ASH      -> AH
>
> ROWAN    -> ROAN (acceptable according to Collins)
>
> HALLO*   -> HALO
>
> MOTOR*   -> MOOR
>
> NOTHING  -> NOTING
>
> CASTS    -> CATS
>
> FARTING  -> FARING
>
> HOUSE*   -> HOSE`

Unsure about the extra Peachy Words™ at the moment, although it could be

> removing three letters from the middle (bigger pits in the peach?) and still end up with a word. But `MOTOR -> MR` which, in my opinion, doesn't quite qualify as a word. It does work for `HALLO -> HO` and `HOUSE -> HE`. But again, `FARTING -> FANG` is good but `FARTING` does not have the star on it. Thanks Ankoganit for reconfirming my suspicions.

Comment: Also, with extra peachy words, you can further remove the two central letters to end up with a valid word once again. Hallo>Halo>Ho, Motor>Moor>Mr., House>Hose>He.

Comment: Good job! Out of curiosity, how did you find the answer? (I'm trying to improve my own skill at solving Word™ puzzles, so tips from those who've succeeded are always helpful.)

Comment: Well, I started by looking at the pattern. As I mentioned in the answer as well, the odd number of letters gave me the first hint. I started with BYE and ASH and removed the last letter, ended up with BY and AH and then extrapolated a bit, but that hit a dead end pretty soon. Then I dropped the middle letter and saw valid words all over the list with that strategy. It was then that the word Peachy threw me off. I was still thinking of the adjective peachy rather than the fruit itself. The pattern being too hard to ignore, I eventually zeroed in on the reason for your choice of name.

Comment: @randal'thor: But if the reasoning is correct, then FARTING also counts as Extra Peachy™.

Comment: @CodeNewbie It is peachier than the others, true (and I hadn't noticed that), but you can't go all the way to FG. So I'll cheat a bit and say that Extra Peachy means you can go all the way :-)

Comment: @randal'thor: Fudging results to prove your theory? I sincerely hope you are not in academia. :P

Comment: @CodeNewbie Touche.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Peachy word means modern words. Now-a-days these words are used instead of the non-peachy words. For example, now we have "seven" days per a week.In Roman days(ancient) days, each week contains "eight" days.

Comment: TJI: Burping is now obsolete. Reroute that gas to the other end.